# Conditional Joins in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Is there any way in Microsoft Access to change how two queries are join based on a certain condition?  I've done this in other environments successfully using a Case statement but I don't think this is possible in Access.

The code below is how I have done this in the past.  Is there anyway to replicate this query in access?

```
select 
A.PROC,
A.MOD1, 
A.MOD2,
A.POS,
B.POS as FRM_T17_POS, 
A.TOS,
B.TOS as FRM_T17_TOS,
A.Specialty,
B.SPCLTY as FRM_T17_Specialty,
A.State,
B.ST_CD as FRM_T17_State,
A.AMT AS FRM_Addendum format dollar10.2,
B.AMT AS FRM_T17 format dollar10.2, 
A.AMT-B.AMT AS DIFF format dollar10.2,
A.EFFECTIVE_DATE1 format=mmddyy10.,
B.BEG AS Beg_T17 format=mmddyy10.,
B.TRM AS Trm_T17 format=mmddyy10.,
B.SYS_SETUP_DT AS T17_SETUP_DT format=mmddyy10.,
C.SYS_PRCD_CD_TRM as Termed_Procs format=mmddyy10. 

From 
pricing.Addendum_001 A
left outer join
pricing.t17_001 B
on
A.PROC = B.PROC
and
A.MOD1 = B.MOD1
and
A.MOD2 = B.MOD2

and 
case when a.Fee_Sch <> '' then
A.Fee_Sch = B.FS
else
A.Fee_Sch = ''
end

and
CASE WHEN A.TOS <> '' THEN
A.TOS = B.TOS
else A.TOS = ''
END

and
CASE WHEN A.STATE <> '' THEN
A.STATE = B.ST_CD
else A.STATE = ''
END

and
CASE WHEN A.Specialty <> '' THEN
A.Specialty = B.SPCLTY
else A.Specialty = ''
END

and
CASE WHEN A.POS <> '' THEN
A.POS = B.POS
else A.POS = ''
END

and 
A.EFFECTIVE_DATE1 < B.TRM
and
A.EFFECTIVE_DATE1 >= B.BEG


left outer join
pricing.TrmdCodes c
on
A.PROC = c.SYS_PRCD_CD

order by 
FS_T17,POS, A.Specialty
```

Comment: Can be constructed in SQLView using IIf() but it won't display in DesignView. If you switch to DesignView the JOIN syntax will be corrupted. The keyword OUTER is not necessary and Access doesn't use it.

Comment: Also, Access is picky about parentheses for multiple JOIN clauses. Good luck. Why need Access version? Is data in SQLServer? Maybe should use pass-through query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think any of your conditions like

```
case when A.X <> '' then
A.X = B.Y
else
A.X = ''
end
```

can be rewritten as

```
(A.X = B.Y OR A.X = '')
```

and such filter is a valid for join condition in the Access query SQL (but when you try to swith to Design mode it says that such expression is not supported by Design mode)